# Setting up Weblate to create pull requests

Tags: github, weblate

I want to use Weblate to help with the localization of an open source project that is developed on GitHub. I don't have write access to the repositories of the maintainers and have to submit pull requests for the improvements I make. It look as if Weblate [supports creating pull requests](https://docs.weblate.org/en/latest/vcs.html#pushing-changes-to-github-as-pull-request), but I can't get it to work.

What I've done so far:

1. Run Weblate 3.4 (in a Docker container) and setup the SSH keys for GitHub access.
2. Set Docker environment variable WEBLATE_GITHUB_USERNAME to my GitHub username.
3. Opened a shell session in the Docker container and run `hub clone octocat/Spoon-Knife` (both as `root` and the `weblate` user; this asks for username and password and the clones the repository; the token is also still there after I restart the Docker containers)
4. Set up a Weblate project.
5. Set up a component in the project.

   - Source code repository = upstream GitHub repo (git@github.com:maintainer/repo)
   - Repository branch = master
   - Repository push URL = my forked GitHub repo (git@github.com:me/repo)
   - Version Control System: GitHub **(EDIT: added on Feb 10 2019)**

**EDIT (Feb 10 2019):**
After finding out that you have to specify "GitHub" as Version Control System when creating a component, Weblate now tries to push changes to the fork and create a pull request. Authentication of the hub tool doesn't work. When I click on "push" in Repository Maintance I get an error. Somewhere in the stack trace there is this error:

`'github.com username: github.com password for  (never stored): '
'Error forking repository: Unauthorized (HTTP 401)\nRequires authentication'`

I strongly suspect that Python can't open `~/.config/hub`. The file definitely exists. Maybe this has to to with how ~ is resolved by Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured it out by myself:

The problem is that '~/.config/hub' is resolved to '/root/.config/hub' when Weblate calls the GitHub hub program. However, the user Weblate is running as is `weblate`, so it doesn't have access to the root's home directory.

I've fixed this by hardcoding '/home/weblate/.config/hub' as the location of the Hub's config file and by making sure the config file is created at this location.

Comment: Hi! Can you describe how you hard-coded the configuration file location? Did this involve modifying some aspect of Weblate? (Edit: I think I see it here... https://github.com/sr258/docker/commit/c8f5b3b94958e43fb73167feaf2a11274907be18#diff-06333407a0507230132851c763c1523aR18)

Comment: Yes, you‘ve found the correct repository. However, the patch is not needed anymore, as Weblate 3.9 runs as non-root in the Docker Container and thus the hub config is read from /home/weblate/.config/hub.